# Выборка из двух таблиц в MySQL

Tags: mysql

В базе имеется 2 таблицы с одинаковыми полями. К примеру, в таблице Table1 есть поле NAME, и в Table2 есть поле NAME. Каким образом можно вывести все данные из обоих таблиц, у которых значение поля NAME = FizLico?

Comment: В вопросе приведите структуру таблиц и, что Вы хотите получить

Comment: Как вывести? Если "сначала данные из одной таблицы, потом из другой", то для этого должно совпадать количество и типы выводимых столбцов в таблице.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, что вам нужно вывести.

Можете попробовать [`UNION`](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_union.html) (при условии, что столбцы в таблице 1 и в таблице 2 одинаковые):

```
select * from (
    select *
    from table1
    where name = 'FizLico'
    UNION /*либо UNION ALL при необходимости сохранения дубликатов*/
    select *
    from table2
    where name = 'FizLico') b
order by client
```

[Пример на sqlfiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/57ac37/3/0)

Comment: Прокатило вот так select * from ip where name = 'FizLico' UNION ALL select * from ip_14 where name = 'FizLico'

Comment: а как потом отсортировать вывод по полю client, ORDER BY в простом запросе из одной таблицы, а из двух?

Comment: @Obloko подправил ответ. Если ответ оказался для вас правильный - не забудьте отметить его галкой напротив.

Comment: ошибка 1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: @Obloko подправил.

Comment: после скобок добавил AS select_result order by client, и все заработало. Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 5):

Плохо понятно, что нужно... попробуй начать с такого:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1, table2
WHERE table1.name = table2.name
  AND table1.name = 'FizLico';
```

Comment: ой СПАСИБО! прям честно, наверное первый понятный пример который я встретил!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT column_name1, column_name2, ...
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name=table2.column_name
WHERE table1.NAME = 'FizLico'
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы получить данные из нескольких таблиц вам нужен какой-то `key` по которому вы будете идентифицировать нужное вам значение а соединение между таблицами происходит с помощью `Inner Join` -
[SQL Joins](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Пример:

```
SELECT <fields>   
FROM tbl1   
INNER JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.<field>=tbl2.<field>
```